# Fourier transform waveform

Tags: fourier-transform

[is this waveform correct for the Fourier transform of a triangle pulse?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF7MG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a (shifted) cardinal sine ($\text{sinc}^2$) which is quite normal.

Indeed, a (non shifted) triangular pulse is the convolution of a window by itself. The Fourier transform of a window is a sinc. Therefore, as convolution is transformed into product by the Fourier Transform, we get the product of two "sinc"s, i.e. a $\text{sinc}^2$. The multiplication by the complex exponential accounts for a (temporal?) shift.

Comment: the e^-4jw shifted it by 4? my waveform center is correct or it should be 0?

Comment: I hadn't understood wether you had the curve as a reult of a software or not. What is the equation of your originaI "temporal" signal ? Seeing a translation in the frequency plane, it means that you had a multiplication of your "tent" signal by a complex exponential in the time plane.

Comment: no, I plotted it by myself  this is the signal in time domain x(t)=5△(t-4/8) (which is a triangular signal)

Comment: therefore it is normal to have a multiplication by $e^{i \tfrac12 [2 \pi] \omega}$ in the frequency domain. But why is the coefficient $5$ becoming $20$ ?

Comment: My main concern is whether the waveform that I shifted for the Sinc function is correct?  and 5 is being multiplied by 4 which we will get in the answer, when we will take Fourier transform of  x(t)=5△(t-4/8)

Comment: I didn't understand because you have forgotten parentheses $x(t)=5 \Delta((t-4)/8)$ ...

Comment: if you will take the fourier transform of this function which is x(t)=5△((t-4)/8)You will get a sinc function which I am getting is       X(w) = 20 exp^-jw4 sinc² (2w) { I was asking that, the waveform that I uploaded earlier was correct as per this equation}

Comment: With formula $\mathscr{F}(f(t))(\nu)=F(\nu) \implies \mathscr{F}(f(at+b))(\nu)=\frac{1}{|a|} e^{-i 2 \pi \nu b/a}F(\nu/a)$ (see here) with $a=1/8,b=−1/2$ doesn't give the desired answer... even if one takes $\omega= 2 \pi \nu $...

Comment: ... for example, the dominant coefficient should be $40$ not $20$. But maybe we don't agree on what the $\Delta$ function is ? Is it $\Delta(t)=1-|t|$ for you ?

Comment: yes its a triangular function